# pan to marker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i've got a problem with setting the center of my map on a marker. I basicly want to find a location and center my map on it. Here's my code:

```
                <script>
            var map;

            function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                center: {lat: 51.9189046, lng: 19.1343786},
                zoom: 6
              });

              // Search for Onninen in Lublin.
              var request = {
                location: map.getCenter(),
                radius: '1000',
                query: 'onninen lublin'
              };



              var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
              service.textSearch(request, callback);
            }


            function callback(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  place: {
                    placeId: results[0].place_id,
                    location: results[0].geometry.location
                  }
                });

                 map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
              } 
            }



            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                </script>
```

I tried a couple different things already. I tried setting the map.center to the marker.position i even tried a simple event to see if it works but everything just crashes. Any help would be nice :)

Comment: What about `map.panTo(results[0].geometry.location);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, 
1) (you probably have this but just in case) you need to include the places library in the url call for the google maps api

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places">
</script>
```

and 2) when you create the marker you need to give it a position explicitly. Here is working code

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 51.9189046,
      lng: 19.1343786
    },
    zoom: 6
  });

  // Search for Onninen in Lublin.
  var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: '1000',
    query: 'onninen lublin'
  };



  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}


function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      place: {
        placeId: results[0].place_id,
        location: results[0].geometry.location
      },
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });

    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
  }
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places">
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: hehe, sorry, my mistake, it already is map.panTo(marker.getPosition()); and doesnt work :)

Comment: @MateuszPawłowski edited answer to reflect your change.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect :)